# Allow requests from certain URL's only

Tags: php, css

I've made a CSS template which I can sell. The css is hosted on my server. I only want site's who paid to have access to this file, so I thought of a php file which echo's the css, only if the url exists in an array.

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/css");

$allowedUrls = ['google.com', 'facebook.com'];

$thisURL = "http://urlfromrequester.com"; //???
$thisURL = str_ireplace('www.', '', $thisURL);
$thisURL = (parse_url($thisURL, PHP_URL_HOST));

foreach ($allowedUrls as $url) {
    if ($url == $thisURL) {
        $css = file_get_contents('theCSSFile.css');
    } else {
        $css = file_get_contents('FileWithLinkToBuyPage.css');
    }
}

echo($css);
```

This is a safe way to only print the css when the host bought the css file. But how can I get the URL of the requester?

People who buy this file will use it like this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    href="http://domain.com/checkLicence.php">`

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that your CSS has to be sent to the client (browser) of the website visitors, so it can be any IP address. This is the browser which interprets the CSS, and not the server. So I don't see the point of blocking CSS files...

On websites that sell templates, you can easily get the CSS, even when it's minified.

Comment: I would suggest having users down the file as a .css file and have them host it themselves under your license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Take into consider though, that the referral address is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. **In short, it cannot really be trusted.**